# Difference between $G$-principal bundle and fiber bundle with fiber $G$?

Tags: definition, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I'm having a hard time understanding principal bundles.

- I understand that a fiber bundle can be defined $(E, B, \pi, F)$ where $E, B, F$ are topological spaces and $\pi: E\to B$ is a surjection. For a fiber bundle, for each $b\in B$ there is a neighborhood $U\supset b$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)\subset E \simeq U\times F$ via homomorphism $\phi$. Also $\text{proj}_1\circ \phi = \pi$.
- I've seen multiple definitions for the principal bundle. One definition is that a principal bundle is a fiber bundle $(E, B, \pi, G)$ where $G$ is a topological group. But in addition, it seems to be important that there is a free and transitive group action of $G$ on $E$ which preserves fibers of $B$ within $E$.

I have a few questions.

- Is the definition I've given for a principal bundle above good? I've seen many different definitions. Some of them involve quotients/orbit spaces, some do not indicate that a principal bundle is defined to have typical fiber $G$, some involve a structure group, etc. I would appreciate if answers to this question include the definition of a principal bundle preferred by the author, possibly with a reference for that definition.
- **THE MAIN QUESTION**: Why is it necessary to specify a group action of $G$ on $E$? Why couldn't we just define a principal bundle to be a fiber bundle whose typical fiber is a group $G$?

Comment: For the main question, because it's useful.  What good is the group structure if you can't use it to slide things around in the total space?  [Groups should act on things.]

Comment: @Randall but if the fibers are already the group $G$ doesn't that mean there is already a natural action of the group $G$ on itself? That is we don't need to specify it additionally? But perhaps a fiber-wise group action is not enough, we need a group action that is continuous on the whole total space $E$ (e.g. between fibers) which is different?

Comment: You just said it!  Right.

Comment: Rough analogy:  the definition of a topological group is not a group with a topology on it.  It is required that the group operations interact with the topology appropriately.  You need the group structure to "do something" and not just lie there.

Comment: @Randall Hmm, there's something I can't put my finger on. I think I'm imagining that if we have a fiber bundle $(E, B, \pi, G)$ that there is already a natural continuous action of $G$ on $E$, maybe that is true in the trivial case but can't be constructed if the bundle is non-trivial.

Comment: @Randall initially you said "What good is the group structure if you can't use it to slide things around in the total space?". I think my counter-response would be, let's define something like a principal bundle that is just a fiber bundle with fiber $G$. Ok, the group elements "attached" to each point in the base space don't act on anything yet. But when we define associated bundles down the road these spaces will need to have $G$-actions defined on them. Then, for example, we could pick a section of the principal bundle and "act" that section on an associated bundle.

Comment: So it's not necessary for the group to act on the total space for the group to get to "act on something". It will always get to act on the associated bundles down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm still learning, this is my stab at an answer, but correction/improvements are much appreciated.

I think the key here is that *the goal* with a principal bundle is to attach **a $G$-torsor** to each point of the base space, **not** to attach the group $G$ to each point of the base space. There is a bit of confusion, however, because a $G$-torsor is always isomorphic to $G$, so you can't attach a $G$-torsor without kind of attaching $G$ as well. This is what makes the definitions a bit confusing.

But then the question arises, why not define a principal bundle as a fiber bundle $(E, B, \pi, T)$ where the fiber $T$ is a $G$-torsor? I think the answer here is that it is not enough for the group $G$ to act independently on/within the various fibers $E_b\subset E$ for $b\in B$, but rather, it is necessary that the group acts continuously on the total space, i.e. globally and continuously **across** fibers as well.

For this, we require a continuous group action of $G$ on $E$ which preserves fibers and which acts freely and transitively on fibers. One possible definition which does this is:

> A principal bundle is a fiber bundle $(E, B, \pi, F)$ together with a continuous group action of $G$ on $E$ which preserves fibers and which acts freely and transitively on fibers.

In fact, I think this definition suffices despite not providing ANY information about the fibers $F$ other than the fact that is a fiber of some fiber bundle. It could indeed be proven as a simple theorem that $F$ is homeomorphic to a $G$-torsor. But then, of course, we could show $F$ is also homeomorphic to $G$.

So this means there is freedom in the definition to (1) specify nothing about $F$, (2) specify that $F$ is a $G$-torsor, or (3) specify that $F$ is $G$. I think this freedom in the definition is where some of my confusion comes from. For example, I think of a vector bundle as attaching a vector space to each point in the base space. For my intuition, should I think of a principal bundle as attaching a group or a torsor to each point of the base space? I think the answer is that it's probably best to think of a principal bundle as attaching a $G$-torsor to each point in the base space. So for this I think the definition that makes no claim about the fiber $F$ is best. It can then be left as a theorem that $F$ is homeomorphic to a $G$-torsor and to $G$ itself.